# How to inccrease Windows disk (dubal boot)?

Tags: ubuntu

I have the following disks:[image]

Microsoft is the first part (52 GB) and Ubuntu is the second part (179 GB)
Is it possible to increase size of Windows disk and decrease size of Ubuntu?

I was trying Gparted software but it seems that i can decrease /dev/sda5 only from the right side (not from the left)